# Redirect to page on successful POST

Tags: php, header

I'm trying to redirect my header upon the success of a certain if statement.

It just is not redirecting. I am doing my POST method then redirecting. Is this not possible? My data submits successfully, it just doesn't redirect.

```
$errors = false;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

if (!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['company']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['question'])) {
        extract($_POST);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `knowledge` (`name`,`company`,`email`,`question`) VALUES ('$name','$company','$email','$question')";
        $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        header("Location: http://www.test.com/thankyou.php");
} else {
    $errors = true;
}

if ($errors) {
    $leftNav .= "<p style='color: red;'>You must fill out all form fields.</p>";
}
}
```

Comment: it mean your condition is always false ..also your code is open for sql injection

Comment: Maybe there is any output being sent to browser before you call header("Location: http://www.test.com/thankyou.php"); Even a blank space in html? check for that

Comment: Place var_dump($_POST); at the end to be sure it receives post data correctly. And after the header() put something like die('Redirecting'); just to know it reaches that part.

Comment: It is getting to the die('redirecting');

Comment: I am submitting my form to the same page on a server[php_self]. Is this why I assume it's not working?

Comment: can you put in echo statement for debugging to check if its even reaching the header statement. May be your  problem lies somewhere above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should turn on error_messaging and display_errors in your dev environment.  That will help you get to the bottom of the issue of things like this right away.

My guess is that you have output to the browser already before doing this redirection.  If you have you error messaging on this would cause a "headers already sent" error and even tell you the line of code where the output was sent to browser.

Also you need to read up on SQL injection and how to prevent it.  You code is very insecure right now. Working with `mysql_*` functions or PDO instead of the deprecated `mysql_*` functions would give you the ability to use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

This code is a mess.

This code seems to be open for a XSS attack with `$_POST['leftnav']`: Don't use extract, because it might overwrite your own variables.

Your code is attackable with all the `$_POST` keys, because they are not escaped: Don't use mysql_query, because it is deprecated and doesn't support prepared statements.

And the answer to your question:
turn on error_reporting:

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1); ?>
```

to check the error. If you have a space or something before the `<?php` php will tell you.